# Generic ORACLE SQL Query for Insert for any table of any number of columns of different data types

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a SQL procedure which can insert data into n tables. Like, there is a table i.e. TABLE1 which has 4 columns of different data type and another table i.e. TABLE2 which has say 6 columns of different data type (not in same order).

And want to create a single procedure which insert into database by providing table name, column name and it's data.

How can I create a single generic procedure to do this?

Comment: Add the desired result: how you want to call the procedure and it's desired result. Something like that: `GenericInsert(table_name, column_name, column_value)`?

Comment: @Mikhail scenario is like, from a page I select a db table and different controls corresponds to columns displayed on screen like if column data type is varchar then text box will be displayed and if column is of datetime type then date control will be displayed.

Comment: Now user can fill the data in these controls and click on say "Insert" button. So, at backend a procedure needs to be created which insert the data into the selected table. So, what I think of for procedure is, it will accept two inputs i.e. 1st will be table name and 2nd will be a refcursor which has the column name and its corresponding value. like: GenericInsert(table_name, refcursor).